# Cannot type inside TextArea when using dynamic index for ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, textarea, angular-ngmodel

This problem is really odd and this example could not be easier :)
The TextArea is somehow blocked.

html

```
<div ng-app> 
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
<div  ng-repeat="x in names">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model="dynamicTextArea[x.ID]">SOS</textarea>{{x.ID}} Why you can't type inside the area???
</div> 
</div>
</div>

<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model="dynamicTextArea" >SOS</textarea>
```

javascript

```
 function ContactController($scope) {
     $scope.names = [
        {
        ID: '5'
         },
        {
        ID: '6'
        },
        {
        ID: '7'
        }
    ];

 }
```

I even created a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/c93qm5Lj/1/

€ 
Here is the rest of the code I actually wanted to do, it may help someone who has been stucked doing this for hours. I guess the syntax killed me.

html

```
<button ng-click="addCommentBox(x.ID)" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Submit comment</button>
```

javascript

```
$scope.addCommentBox = function(myID) { 
                  alert($scope.dynamicTextArea[myID]);                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found my stupid mistake.

```
$scope.dynamicTextArea = {};
```

You have to initialize them. 
But I could swear I did try it before and it was not working anyway O_O

Comment: Why are you using x.ID with ng-model?

Comment: I need to create dynamic textareas and be able to get the values in my $scope. I couldnt come up with another solution. I edited my first post with the whole stuff I wanted to do.